# I'll talk about the joy of learning and sharing that learning with others

Tags: sentence-meaning

I read that sentence on the subtitles of a video and after reading, I wondered if the sentence means as follows

> I will talk about the joy of learning and the joy of sharing that
> learning with others.

or the joy has nothing to do with the second part of the sentence.

If you want to say the sentence I wrote above, do you think you would add a second "of" or "the joy of" before the word sharing.

Maybe I could not understand the sentence in the first place? What does it mean?

Comment: Yes, it means what you think, but I had to read it twice. A comma after the first _learning_  might make it clearer.

Comment: joy of x, joy of learning and joy of sharing that learning.

Comment: As the original sentence stands, it's open to interpretation. If joy is to explicitly *not* apply to the second part of the sentence, that needs to be made more clear: *I'll talk about (1) the joy of learning and (2) sharing that learning with others.* Or: *I'll talk about the joy of learning, and then about sharing that learning with others.*

Comment: How about "sharing that learning with others" part? How would you reword it?

Comment: For example : " ...sharing after learning with others"